# Matching some capturing groups multiple times

Tags: python, regex

I have a question regarding regex in Python.
I have input strings in the following format:

`@Team1 name="John Black" hobby="reading" job="software engineer"`

I would like to extract Team, name, hobby, and job with regex. Expected output:

```
Team:
Team1

name:
John Black

hobby:
reading

job:
software engineer
```

I came up with this regex:

```
(?P<tags>(?<=\@)\w*) (?P<k>\w*)=(?P<v>\"[\w\s]*\")
```

I know this only matched until the name, I am wondering how I should get the key-value pairs after the name?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a regular expression problem.  This is a parsing problem.  Just read it character by character, keeping track of your current state: "looking for name", "gathering name", "gathering string", etc.

Comment: @tim yes, that is very true. It would be very easy to parse the string, but I need to do it with regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, but why do you *need* to do it with regex? that part hasn't been explained clearly in the question.

Comment: @rv.kcetch sorry I didn't know I had to explain that part, because my assignment is about regular expressions. maybe the example I gave wasn't great, it's basically a tag followed by a series of key-value pairs separated by spaces.

Comment: Well, the example itself was fine, but a little more clarification on *why* the regex part was a requirement would have been nice. The reason I brought this up is because it's actually relatively straightforward to implement this without regex (and potentially also faster)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you capture tag first and, the only way is to generate one type of captured group and then repeat it:

```
(?:^\@(?P<tag>\w*) )?(?:(?:(?P<k>\w+)=(?P<v>\"[\w\s]+\"))+)(?:\@$)?
```

check the result [Here](https://regex101.com/r/HB8tLl/3)

```python
pattern=r"(?:^\@(?P<tag>\w*) )?(?:(?:(?P<k>\w+)=(?P<v>\"[\w\s]+\"))+)(?:\@$)?"
strp='@Team1 name="John Black" hobby="reading" job="software engineer"@'
r = re.compile(pattern)
res=[m.groupdict() for m in r.finditer(strp)]
```

res:

```
[{'tag': 'Team1', 'k': 'name', 'v': '"John Black"'},
 {'tag': None, 'k': 'hobby', 'v': '"reading"'},
 {'tag': None, 'k': 'job', 'v': '"software engineer"'}]
```

Comment: I would probably use two regular expressions in this situation: one to find tag and attributes, the other to finditer through those attributes.

Comment: Me too. But based on the comment: "need to do it with regular expressions", I supposed that it is a practice for one shot solution!